# mariadb import - all rows missing except those in final INSERT of InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, mysqldump

This is a very strange bug. I'm using this on a mac:

**mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.6-MariaDB, for osx10.13 (x86_64)**

If I import an SQL dump of a WordPress DB (so not very complicated structure, but some long lines) from the command line, the table structure for all tables appears normal, but lots of content is missing from InnoDB tables.

Specifically, where the INSERTS have been 'chunked' into groups of records, only the final group is there.  If I use `--skip-extended-insert` to write a statement for every record, **only one record** is ever in the InnoDB table.

**MyISAM data seems fine. Using MySQL 8.0.16 is fine, it's MariaDB that isn't.**

(I've tried dropping and recreating the database).

Note: I had very similar, possibly identical, problem with Drupal on MariaDB recently when clearing the cache - which rebuilds the router table, but many rows were missing.

Comment: Have you tried it on an older version?

Comment: @RickJames it's installed with homebrew, so I can't easily roll back to a previous version. I've just switched from mariadb back to mysql (Ver 8.0.16 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)) and that's ok.  I had a very similar problem with Drupal recently so maybe I need to be reporting this somewhere…

Comment: You can report it here: https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/MDEV

Comment: @dbdemon - Thank you - finally got around to [filing a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20354) for this - in the meantime I also noticed it only happens if you lock the table for writes first.  There's also a [Drupal issue here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3066443)